# На wordpress-сайте не появляется блок "Поделиться" от Яндекс

Tags: javascript, ya-share2

Этот код вставлен в файл single.php шаблона Wordpress, но на страницах он не показывается. Кэш очищен. В чем может крыться причина?

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" async="async"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-
services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus,twitter,linkedin,lj"></div>
```

Comment: Режет баннерорезка?

Comment: Этот код попадает в итоговый html страницы?